# Finding the source of `querySelectorsFromElement` error

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, safari

In my app, I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'element.querySelectorAll')
```

With stacktrace:

```
@https://www.example.com/path/:699:37
asyncFunctionResume@[native code]
querySelectorsFromElement@https://www.example.com/path/:698:46
querySelectorsFromElement@[native code]
```

Google literally returns nothing when searching for `querySelectorsFromElement`.

According to my logs, all these issues seem to be happening from Safari on iOS or OS X. And considering the last stack line `querySelectorsFromElement@[native code]`, it seems this does not originate from my code.

Does anyone know what would be causing this? Should it be safe to ignore this error?